# bokeh trigger js_on_change for first display of graph

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I am plotting a bokeh graph ftom a pandas datasource in my website.
The pandas dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
X   Y   Type
0   5    A
0   15   B
1   12   A
1   18   B
```

I add a `Select` object with values `A` and `B`. Basically, the user selects the value `A` or `B` in that select object, and my `CustomJS` callback filters the DataSource and plots the graph corrresponding to the selected type:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
select = Select(title="Select Type:", options=['A', 'B'])
callback = CustomJS(args={'source':source}, code = """
    var t = cb_obj.value
    var a = df.filter(function(c){if (c['Type'] == t) return c;});
    source.data['X'] = []
    source.data['Y'] = []
    for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
      source.data['X'].push(a[i]['%s']);
      source.data['Y'].push(a[i]['Y']);
    }
    source.change.emit();
  """
select.value = 'A'
```

The problem is that the graph looks messy when it is first displayed. Indeed it plots all the `X` and `Y` columns, and I have to manually change the default selected type in the dropdown to get the callback triggered and the data correctly filtered.

Can I smehow trigger that callback programmatically before first display of my graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to trigger the callback up front. Instead, you should make sure (in Python) that the CDS is initialized to the correct initial state that you actually want to be displayed.

However, if what you are trying to do is select between subsets of the data then the approach you have above cannot work. You are actually updating the only data source you have, with will *throw away data* on every callback (that you cannot get back). Instead you should use the select callback to configure a Bokeh filter:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#filtering-data

Specifically you probably want a `GroupFilter` and there is some example/discussion on the Discourse:

https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/scatter-plot-legend-doesnt-update-correctly-when-data-is-updated/5545

Comment: My dataframe exists in the browser. I am sending it through my renderer. I am using tornado

Comment: None of that is relevant or changes my answer.  You create the CDS in Python code, that is where you need to make sure it is initialized correctly. Your DataFrame absolutely does not exist in the browser in any literal sense, since the browser only knows JavaScript and knows absolutely nothing about Python or Pandas. A `CustomJS` callback, as the name suggests, executes *only JavaScript code*.

Comment: I've upated with a link to the Uer's Guide section on filtering since it seems that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware that I could filter the data in Python before first plot